# MSI RX1950 Pro-Series PCI-E video card - Is there a way to make 3D functions work?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, ati, proprietary

I have the 3D-Card in the subject. It is ATI-based.
I know proprietary driver support for Linux has been dropped a while ago, so I have been struggling for years now, with no success... my high-performance 3D card works as a standard VGA only.

That is why I currently run with Unity-2D.

Even trying the xorg-edgers ppa is not make it work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully managed to make my X1550 work perfectly using the 300g Gallium driver, it involved installing from Xrog-edgers PPA, but I did all that in Ubuntu 10.10. Now, the 300g drivers come by default with Ubuntu 11.04, so that's strange!

First let's see what's being used, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Then, run: `glxinfo | grep -i opengl`

Normally you should get:

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RVXXX
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.11-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

Now let's make sure the drivers are in place, type these in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Comment: That is what I get:

`OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:'

Comment: Your driver isn't installed/configured. I'll update the answer.